# How To Start Learn Cryptography With C#?

Tags: c#, security, cryptography

I want to learn about Cryptography theory (basics) and I want to use the algorithms in c#.
So I need some guides , books , tutorials to get start.

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

read [Practical Cryptography](http://www.schneier.com/book-practical.html) by niels ferguson and bruce schneier.  You might also want to read Bruce's previous (older, but still very cool) book - [Applied Cryptography](http://www.schneier.com/book-applied.html).

They won't teach you *everything* you want to know - but it will dispel a lot of myths and teach you a lot of the theory and practise.

There's no code in them but the reason I've plumped for a language-independent answer is because after learning the different types of cryptography and how to use them, use of the primitives in C# is significantly easier.

After that, in my opinion, the MSDN becomes the primary reference for how to use those primitives.

Answer (score 2):

This [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164055.aspx) may help you [Updated: Archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140827212033/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164055.aspx)
Article originally published in MSDN Magazine in November 2003.

Comment: The "linked" article is no longer available. I did find it on Archive.org. It's a pretty good article from approx November 2003. So .NET 1.1 references.

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest [Beginning Cryptography with Java](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-Cryptography-with-Java.productCd-0764596330.html) by David Hook. The book uses Java, and so is not ideal for you. But Java and C# are similar enough that it should be helpful. And the author of the book is the maintainer of the Bouncycastle crypto libraries, which include a Java and C# library that are almost identical. Most of the book's examples should translate easily to C#.

Answer (score 1):

Once you're past Schneier's excellent introduction, "Applied Cryptography", I suggest reading [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://www.cacr.math.uwaterloo.ca/hac/), it contains all the details that would have cluttered Schneier's book, but are required for anyone interested in actual implementation of secure protocols and programs.

(Once you read it, you may better understand why everyone relies on cryptographic libraries such as OpenSSL, GnuTLS, Crypto++, and so forth.)

Comment: couldn't agree more - you're inference here being "don't roll your own unless you really do know what you're doing!"

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/dotnetcryptog.aspx
ALso see 
http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/ASP.NET/Cryptographic-Objects-in-C-sharp-Part-1/

Answer (score 0):

These may help:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Articles/ArticleListing.aspx?SectionID=1&SubSectionID=60

[http://www.amazon.com/Data-Security-Handbook-Matthew-MacDonald/dp/1861008015](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1861008015)